# SSRS Report Expression, for 2 fields in one column

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

I'm creating a report, and I'm trying to have two fields displayed one or the other in the one column= `Account Name`.

See my problem is, if I run the report with one of fields some some of the account names are populated

For example:

`Table 1`[image: Example 1]

`Table 2`[image: Example 2]

If I use 1 set of `Account Name` and Address fields, only some Name/Address fields are populated like in Table 1.

If I use the other set of Account Name and Address fields, only some Name/Address fields are populated like in Table 2.

How can I use the 2 sets in an `Expression`, so that all the Name/Address fields are populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've solved it,*

```
=Fields!Addr1.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Addr2.Value),"",VbCRLF & Fields!Addr2.Value)
```